# POI and Excel Lists or Tables

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

There is a requirement to read multiple Excel "Lists" from one sheet in an Excel file.
I need to know if there is an inbuilt method/api to obtain the dimensions of a list or deal with list specific data. At the bare minimum, is there a way of knowing the "headers" of the list and the number of rows contained in the list data?

I want the POI wrapper that I am writing to be aware of the data elements on the excel, rather than being told through properties/constants or worse; hardcoding the names of the headers/size of the list.

Regards, Vinu
PS: No idea whether the question made any sense...but anyone who gets my drift...please!

Answer (score 0):

I've just written something to do this. AFAIK, Poi itself doesn't understand lists/tables, but you can easily write a wrapper that does. Alternatively, there is the [jxls project](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/) - this allows complex mappings from POJOs to spreadsheets, and has [table reader](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/reader.html) functionality.

[How to: Excel Files](http://rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0516.html) has a number of links to projects that might be useful, including an Excel JDBC driver.